# How to do IPC with UAC elevation safely?

Tags: windows, security, design-patterns, ipc, uac

i have portions of my program that require administrative access (settings that affect all users, stored in HKLM, and are limited to administrative access).

i've changed my software to indicate that elevation is required:

[image]

In response i am going to launch my executable while prompting for elevation:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO shExecInfo;
shExecInfo.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
shExecInfo.fMask = NULL;
shExecInfo.hwnd = NULL;
shExecInfo.lpVerb = L"runas";
shExecInfo.lpFile = L"myapp.exe";
shExecInfo.lpParameters = NULL;
shExecInfo.lpDirectory = NULL;
shExecInfo.nShow = SW_MAXIMIZE;
shExecInfo.hInstApp = NULL;
ShellExecuteEx(&shExecInfo);
```

What i was *going* to do is pass the name of a named pipe on the command line, telling myself where it can connect back to in order to get instructions on what it's supposed to be doing:

```
myapp.exe /uac 6C844671-E262-46DD-939E-47517F105FB6
```

(Yes, using a GUID as the name of the pipe).

Through this pipe i would tell my elevated clone what database, e.g.:

- what server database it's supposed to be connecting to
- the user it should say it making the changes
- the thing it should add/edit/delete

My concern was then that anyone could launch `myapp.exe`, and then feed it all kinds of requests - things i don't want it to do cause **i** didn't launch it, e.g.:

**MaliciousProgram.exe**:

```
 ShellExecute("myapp.exe /uac HahaYouDoWhatISayNow")
```

i remember during the Longhorn beta there was a Channel9 video, or an article, talking about UAC and the dangers of the wrong of doing IPC (Inter-process communication).

i don't want to re-invent the wheel, making security mistakes that have already been solved. But i cannot find any existing guidance on the "*correct*" way to do IPC with UAC elevation.

What't he accepted pattern for doing IPC to communicate with spawned elevated process for temporary elevated actions?

---

**Edit:** Combined followers of `uac` and `ipc` tags: 53

Comment: I wonder - it's been about five years since you asked the question. Did you ever end up with a satisfactory solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a security issue here (with certain caveats as noted below).  If the user can't elevate, this solution won't work anyway; if the user can elevate, and is malicious, the machine is already compromised.  For example, if a malicious user wants to make changes in HKLM, why use myapp.exe when regedit is available?

However, I'm confused by your mention of a server database; how does this fit in with the requirement for elevation?  Generally speaking elevation is not required for accessing remote resources.  (If either myapp.exe or HKLM contains a password to the server database, it shouldn't.)

As for the choice of IPC: I'm not expert in UAC programming, but searching MSDN I've noticed that elevated COM objects are mentioned several times, e.g.:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx

see also the powerpoint slides at the fifth link in this article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756996.aspx

However, if you're not happy with COM (join the club!) then using a named pipe as you suggest should be just as effective.  You do however need to take the usual precautions necessary for named pipes - make sure that you create the server end of the named pipe before launching the elevated process, that you check whether the pipe already existed, and that you create it with an appropriate ACL.

Comment: The problem is that if my **elevated** process is listening on a pipe: nothing is stopping a **non-elevated** process from sending commands over the same pipe. Worse still would be the non-elevated process exploiting a buffer-overflow bug in my code. Now a non-elevated process is able to run arbitrary code elevated.

Comment: You just need to set the ACL on the pipe correctly.  Setting nMaxInstances to 1 would also be a sensible precaution.  If you were feeling especially paranoid, you could hash the instructions you're going to be sending to the privileged process and include the hash on the command line.

Comment: Also, remember that any non-elevated process running in the same user account is always going to be able to subvert your non-elevated process if it wants to send malicious instructions to the elevated process.  Therefore, you only need to protect the pipe against other user accounts; trying to protect it against other processes in the same account would be pointless.

Comment: i'm not worried about a non-elevated process trying to bully my non-elevated process. i'm worried about a non-elevated process trying to bully my elevated process.

Comment: If your elevated process is taking orders from your non-elevated process, is there any practical difference?

Comment: Difference is between *me* sending intended commands, verses a malicious program sending disruptive commands. And this question exists to get feedback on how to ensure that my application's temporary need to elevate does not become an attack vector for malicious software - and best practices to limit the user's vulnerability when using my software.

Comment: The only way to prevent your elevated process from being an attack vector is for it to not take instructions from the non-elevated process, or at least not without authenticating them with the user.  In other words, it needs to have its own GUI.  There is no way to stop a malicious program from changing the commands that your non-elevated process sends to the elevated process.

Comment: @IanBoyd did you ever figure out a solution to this problem? Unfortunately, the only solution I've been able to figure out so far is a massively over-engineered PKI approach. Either use a pre-determined key pair, or the unelevated process can generate a random key pair and launch the elevated process with the public key as a commandline arg. Then you could use an encrypted channel, which would guarantee commands came from a credible source. But that's a MASSIVE overkill...

Comment: @YasharBahman: there is no solution.  What you're trying to do is impossible.  PKI won't solve it either, because a malicious process running in the same user context can always steal the PKI keys from your unelevated process.  You **cannot** erect a security boundary between processes that are running in the same security context.